# Set DataGridView Row Background Image in C# Winform Application

Tags: c#, winforms, background-image

I am working on a Windows form application where I need to set background image to the data row of data-grid view. For example if i am having 4 rows in my data grid, I want to repeat a image to the rows background but not to the whole grid-view. Image should be set as background image so that I can have text above the image. How could I achieve this? Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like :

```
Image img;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    img = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Pictures\1.jpg");
}

private void GV_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(img, new Point(0, 0));
}
```

Comment: Its adding the image but problem is with the small size image as image not stretching though out the row.

Answer (score 0):

Add image to `Resources` in your Visual Studio project

Then in your `MyDataGridView` set (through Designer or by code) `DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Transparent`

And finally add event handler for `.RowPrePaint`

```
//In constructor
MyDataGridView.RowPrePaint += new EventHandler(MyDataGridView_RowPrePaint);

//Create event handler
private void MyDataGridView_RowPrePaint(Object sender, DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(My.Resources.MyImage, e.RowBounds);
}
```

If you need set `DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Transparent` too...